# Express-session - No reconoce el usuario en req.session

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose, postman, express-session

Tengo un proyecto de mi curso de programación  backend en donde estoy trabajando con una aplicación ecommerce la cual contiene un formulario de registro para iniciar sesión y registrarse, una vista de productos usando handlebars a la cual el usuario se redirige al iniciar sesión en la página web y un carrito de compras en el cual se muestran los productos que elige el usuario.

En el código de mi archivo principal importo varias dependencias, entre esas dependencias está express-session que la tengo configurada de esta manera en mi archivo principal:

```
//========={ Dependencias }=========
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import exphbs from 'express-handlebars';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';



//==== Dependencia que maneja las sesiones ====
import session from 'express-session';
//==== Dependencia que maneja las sesiones ====



import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';
import initializePassport from './config/passport.config.js';
import passport from 'passport';
import flash from 'connect-flash';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
//========={ Dependencias }=========


import __dirname from './utils.js';
import cartsRouter from './routes/api/carts.router.js';
import productsRouter from './routes/api/products.router.js';
import viewsProductRouter from './routes/web/views.products.js';
import sessionsRouter from './routes/api/sessions.router.js';
import viewsRouter from './routes/web/views.router.js';

import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { getProducts } from './routes/web/views.products.js';
import { getCart } from './routes/web/views.products.js';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());  
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(flash());

const hbs = exphbs.create({
    helpers: {
    debug: function (value) {
        console.log("Current Context");
        console.log("====================");
        console.log(this);

        if (value) {
        console.log("Value");
        console.log("====================");
        console.log(value);
        }
    },
    },
});

app.engine("handlebars", hbs.engine);
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`);


let mongooseConnection;

const environment = async () => {
    try {
        mongooseConnection = await mongoose.connect('Aquí van los datos para conectarme a mi mongodbAtlas');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
}


async function main() {
    await environment();
}

main();

//======= Configuración de express-session =======
app.use(session({
    store: MongoStore.create({
        client: mongoose.connection.getClient(),
        ttl: 3600
    }),
    secret: 'Coder39760',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
//======= Configuración de express-session =======

//PASSPORT
initializePassport();
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use("/", viewsProductRouter);
app.use("/api/products", productsRouter);


//====== Ruta del carrito de compras ======
app.use("/api/carts", cartsRouter);
//====== Ruta del carrito de compras ======


app.use("/api/sessions", sessionsRouter);
app.use("/", viewsRouter);

const server = app.listen(8080);
const io = new Server(server);

app.on('cartUpdated', async cartId => {
const productsData = await getProducts();
io.emit('products', productsData.products);

const cartData = await getCart(cartId);
io.emit('cart', cartData.products);
});

app.set('socketio', io);
io.sockets.setMaxListeners(20);
```

En ese código que pasé de mi archivo principal hay dos puntos importantes en que fijarse, en la parte del código que señalé en el comentario que dice "Dependencia que maneja las sesiones" y el que dice "Ruta del carrito de compras", porque en esa ruta del carrito de compras tengo este método:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("En carts.router.js: " + JSON.stringify(req.session));
    console.log("En carts.router.js: " + req.user);

    if (!req.user) {
        // Si el usuario no ha iniciado sesión
        return res.status(401).send({ status: "error", error: "Debe iniciar sesión para crear un carrito" });
    }

    const { products } = req.body;

    try {

        const result = await cartManager.create({
            products
        });

        res.send({ status: "success", payload: result })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ status: "error", error });
    }
});
```

Que es el método que uso para poder crear un carrito, y como se puede apreciar puse una condición if (!req.user), lo que quiere decir que si la cookie (me refiero a la cookie que crea la dependencia express-session para almacenar los datos del usuario cuando se registra) no tiene el usuario entonces no puede crear un carrito, lo que hace que detecte cuando un usuario se registra, pero cuando veo en consola los valores que tienen req.session (la cookie de la sesión) y req.user (el usuario de la cookie) obtengo esto:

```
En carts.router.js: {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
En carts.router.js: undefined
```

Me dice que la cookie no tiene el usuario y el valor del usuario es indefinido, cosa que no debería pasar porque en otros archivos donde he puesto esos console.log de req.user y req.session yo obtengo algo como esto:

```
En views.products.js:  {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"passport":{"user":"648cd158490f37fe04a77179"}}
En views.products.js: {
  _id: new ObjectId("648cd158490f37fe04a77179"),
  first_name: 'Oliver',
  last_name: 'Zapata',
  email: 'zapata@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$LKiLPZIP8747XXCHoer5SekvNExXoFFy9TOK1x73x.cGfgSoEWAMq',
  role: 'user',
  __v: 0
}
```

Y como se puede ver en el archivo views.products.js (donde se ve la vista de productos de la aplicación) si se ve el usuario en la cookie, el problema sucede cuando yo desde postman ejecuto el método post para crear un carrito dándome como resultado el error que configuré en esta condición:

```
if (!req.user) {
        // Si el usuario no ha iniciado sesión
        return res.status(401).send({ status: "error", error: "Debe iniciar sesión para crear un carrito" });
    }
```

Y por eso no me crea el carrito, y no entiendo porque pasa, ¿algo está mal con la configuración de express-session en el archivo principal?, ¿o es que estoy me falta algo a la hora de hacer llamar al método post con postman? (Quiero aclarar una cosa, si yo quito la condición que puse para que el usuario solo pudiera crear un carrito si está registrado entonces el método si funciona y creo un carrito correctamente, el problema surge cuando yo pongo esa condición)